# Project cannot find right version of dll, but dll isn't included in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a project that when I try to run it returns an error saying that it cannot find a certain version of a dll. I've managed to fix issues like this before by replacing the file with the version it is after but this problem is different as the dll it is complaining about isn't actually included in the solution, neither is it being referenced to by any of my code.

Is it possible that one of the references I have included is looking to this dll? If so how can I find which one it is, and how would I change the version it is looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered a tool called JustDecompile by Telerik that lets you open up dlls and see whats inside them. This includes both classes and other dlls that they reference. From that I found that the problematic dll was being referenced by this one. So I was able to update the version and all is well